# scroll h:selectOneMenu jsf

Tags: html, css, jsf

I have a `h:selectOneMenu` element with elements from an array list

```
<h:selectOneMenu class="select_3" value="#{Bean.choosenList}"
                        valueChangeListener="#{Bean.getChoosenListId}">
        <f:ajax render=":contact-form:choosenList :contact-form:list-contact-table :contact-form:error_mess"
                            execute="@this" event="valueChange" />
        <f:selectItem itemValue="" itemLabel="" />
        <f:selectItems value="#{Bean.userList}" var="l" itemLabel="#{l.listName}" itemValue="#{l.listId}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

The list now loaded is paginated, I need to add more lists (append to the first list) each time the user scrolls down, I used to get `scroll event` on a div to get if it is scrolled, but with a select element this way won't work. Appreciate your help

Comment: You choose the incorrect event.

Comment: How do you suggest I load the data in the select element? and what is the right event?